# Proving that $t^{p^r}-a$ is irreducible when $a\in k$ is not a $p$th power

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

> Let $p$ be an odd prime, $F$ a field of characteristic $0$ and $a\in F$ with $a\neq 0$. Assume $a$ is not a $p$th power in $F$. Prove that for every positive integer $r$, $t^{p^r}-a$ is irreducible in $F[t]$.

I tried for a long time to prove this by induction, but I don't find the answer. It would be a relief if someone had a proof.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at Lang's *Algebra*, p.297, which has a more general analysis of when $x^n-a$ is irreducible.

Comment: First prove the result for $r=1$ and then prove that if $\lambda$ is a $p$th root of $a$ in $F$ then $\lambda\neq \omega^p$ is not a $p$th power in $F(\lambda)$ (otherwise you will have $N_{F(\lambda)/F}(\lambda)=(-1)^{p+1}a=a$ and then $N_{F(\lambda)/F}(\omega)$ is a $p$th root of unty in $F$ contradiction). Now use induction using Capelli's theorem (If you still need help I could provide a complete answer)