# $a \in \Bbb F_p $ but $a^{1/p} \not \in F_p$ proof that $f(x)=x^{p^n}-a $ is Irreducible over $F_p[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

$a \in \Bbb F_p $ but $a^{1/p} \not \in F_p$ proof that $f(x)=x^{p^n}-a $ is Irreducible over $F_p[x]$

I know only the case when $n=1$
than if $\alpha$ is the root of the polynomial so  $x^p-a= x^p-\alpha ^p =(x-\alpha)^p$ and so $\alpha$ is anti saperable root of the polynomial $f_\alpha$
its degree  $deg(f_\alpha)\ge p $ but $ f_\alpha| x^p-a$  while $x^p-a$ is a fixed polynomial with a degree of $p$ so $f_\alpha (x)=x^{p}-a$ is Irredcible over $F_p(x)$

how I proof the case for $n > 1$?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683269/prove-that-a-polynomial-is-irreducible-or-the-field-contains-a-pth-root?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Please be kind to aged mathematicians with failing vision, and **never** use both $a$ and $\alpha$ in the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awfully sorry, but you’ve gone astray. For $a\in\Bbb F_p$, $a^p=a$, so that $X^p-a=(X-a)^p$ can not be irreducible in $\Bbb F_p[X]$.