# Irreducibility of $ X^{p^{n}}-a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Suppose that $\text{char}(F)=p\neq\emptyset$, and let

$$f= X^{p^{n}}-a\in F[X],\, \text{for some}\, n\in\mathbb N.$$

I need to prove that

1. The irreducible factorization of $f$ in $F[X]$ has the form $f= \big(X^{p^{k}}-c\big)^{p^{n-k}}$ for some $c\in F$.
2. $f$ is irreducible in $F[X]$ iff $a\notin F^p.$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Excuse me, I'm going to correct the formula

Comment: @AxeL you are right

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683269/prove-that-a-polynomial-is-irreducible-or-the-field-contains-a-pth-root) answer your question?